# React components can not get the right argument when passing closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react to write a page to show pictures in browser. I'm using the following code to render a picture-show-block

```
renderPicShowBlock= () => {
    if (this.state.records)
    {
        let picBlocks = []

        for (const record of this.state.records) {
            picBlocks.push(
                <PicShowBlock user={this.state.user}
                              key={record.id}
                              record={record}
                              onItemDelete={()=>this.handleItemDelete(record.id)}
                />
            )
        }
        return picBlocks
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

`handleItemDelete` is defined as an arrow function:

```
handleItemDelete= (id) => {
    axios.post("/core/data/record/",
        {"action": "delete", "item_id": id}).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response.data)
        this.init_record()
    })

}
```

The problem is when I call `onItemDelete` in this component, the record in this closure get stuck **pointing to the last record** in `this.state.records`. I was thinking that it might be that "JS closure trap" caused by JS glocal scpoe, but it seems not. What does this problem come from? Is that caused by closure or some code logic bugs?

I used create-react-app to setup this project.

Comment: only `onItemDelete` can not get the right record id, the other argument can get the right result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found that it was caused by another issue. It is because that the logic to process deletebutton's id is wrong, The Bootstrap's javascript pick another delete button from anothor ShowBlock

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it around:

```
                <PicShowBlock user={this.state.user}
                              key={record.id}
                              record={record}
                              onItemDelete={this.handleItemDelete(record.id)}
                />
```

and

```js
handleItemDelete= (id) => () => {
    axios.post("/core/data/record/",
        {"action": "delete", "item_id": id}).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response.data)
        this.init_record()
    })

}
```

This way, `this.handleItemDelete(record.id)` will be executed immediately with the right `record` and the function just returns the callback you want on your component.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It's too wired. I bind the function by `onClick={this.props.onItemDelete}` in the component. It still get the wrong id. I check the scope in chrome. I found that when call this function, the scope chain always point the the last call of binding function of `onClick={this.props.onItemDelete}`

Comment: You notice that I did `onItemDelete={this.handleItemDelete(record.id)}` above?

Comment: Yes, I know your what you mean. I tried but it still not work.